# How can I use one function for 2 arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

So here is my code :

```
p2=[]
p1=[]
def arraypoint(x,y):
    if len(p1)>2:
        p2.append(x)
        p2.append(y)
      
    else:
        p1.append(x)
        p1.append(y)
       
    return p2,p1
```

what I want to do is taking x,y coordinates from user and adding them to my arrays.However if I compile that function with code down below:

```
arraypoint(3,4)
arraypoint(2,3)
```

it just adds p1 four elements which is logical because when I run the function again it takes len(p1)==0 .So can you help me how can I add 2 elements to p1 and pass rest of them to p2 . I dont want to do something like `arraypoint(x,x1,y,y1)` so user should pass 2 coordinates each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is working well, but your logic is not correct. you define `if len(p1)>2` so when your first and second call of function is doesn't go in the `if` statement because the condition is not satisfied.

for the output you want  try `if len(p1)>=2` in function.

Comment: Yes i can see while i am working on something different missed such a small logical mistake

Answer (score 0):

`len(p1)` returns `2` and if you use `>` it means it must be minimum `3`